# Java app architecture - need a name for logging, want to keep classes uncoupled

Tags: java, logging, architecture

I'm using a third party software library with a log prototype like this:

```
runtime.getInstance().log(int logtype, String moduleName, String logtext);
```

I have a utility library that I want to be library independent, but I also want to be able to log things to the software package from my own classes. This is fine and good, as the text messages are pretty universal, things like "you've passed bad data!" and "blah blah was successful!" Additionally, I've already wrapped the software vendor's logging functionality, so I'm not even worried about conforming to some random API.

What I am worried about (why I'm writing this post) is that there are going to be various different modules throughout my system. So the problem is like:

```
ModuleFoo extends com.thirdpartyvendor.BaseModule
ModuleBar extends com.thirdpartyvendor.BaseModule
```

`ModuleFoo` ---contains instance of---> `IndependentDataStructure` ---tries to write a log entry to my `WrappedLogger` ---> but data structure doesn't have a reference to `ModuleFoo`.

`ModuleBar` ---contains instance of---> `IndependentDataStructure` ---tries to write a log entry to my `WrappedLogger` ---> but data structure doesn't have a reference to `ModuleBar`.

Currently my system passes a field `String moduleName` around which quite frankly makes me sick... but I want the log entries to tell me what my module is! How can the logger know whether the `IndependentDataStructure` instance is working with `ModuleFoo` and not `ModuleBar` (or some other module) without `IndependentDataStructure` containing a reference to a `BaseModule` (or a `String moduleName`)?

Comment: Is the module responsible for instantiating / preparing the independent data structure? If so you could inject a proxy logger that handles setting the correct module name, and the data structure uses that proxy like .log(logtype, logtext) and the proxy decorates that call with the correct module name.

Comment: But I'd still have to pass around the proxy logger everywhere, right?

Comment: You would have to pass a reference to the correct proxy (aka Decorator) to the data structure when the module initializes / constructs it, yes. If you can bind the used module name to the thread-local diagnostic context as proposed by @Ian Roberts you could let the logger retrieve the module name from there - the data structure wouldn't need to know anything about module names. But that depends on your usage scenario, cannot tell that from the code you provided (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging APIs such as Log4J and SLF4J have the concept of a *diagnostic context*, a way to store various bits of contextual information in a `ThreadLocal` map which the log message formatters can access to decorate the messages.  Typical uses for this are things like putting the name of the currently authenticated user into log messages in a web application (using a servlet filter to store the username in the MDC for each request), would you be able to use a similar concept in your system?

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for, but I need to read the Log4J documentation to be sure.

Comment: Can I use `org.apache.log4j.NDC` without using the other Log4J functionality? Just use `NDC.push(moduleName)` when entering module code, `NDC.pop()` when exiting it, and `NDC.peek()` in my `WrappedLogger`?

Comment: I thought this was funny, from `NDC.inherit()` [javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html): In java, a child thread cannot obtain a reference to its parent, unless it is directly handed the reference. Consequently, there is no client-transparent way of inheriting diagnostic contexts. Do you know any solution to this problem?

Comment: @durron597 Use the newer `MDC` instead of the `NDC` - the former is properly passed from parent to child threads.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know this works perfectly. It took a little doing because of the 3rd party multithreading architecture but with some trial and error I'm saving the context in all the right places. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
runtime.getInstance().log(int logtype, 
                          this.getClass().getSimpleName(), 
                          String logtext);
```

If i've got it right...

EDIT: and for automated (but a bit slowly) auto-method name:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[level].getMethodName();
```

(where level is an integer specifies the number of classes through the log request is passed)

Comment: `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` will return `IndependentDataStructure` not `ModuleFoo`. It doesn't help me to know which `BaseModule` is causing a problem if my log is full of `IndependentDataStructure`.... but `for(StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) { if (ste.getClassName().contains("Module")) } ` would work... but it's kind of a gross hack